# couchdb how to get doc by id in map function

Tags: dictionary, couchdb

Suppose we have two types of documents. One - stores meta data, many others - have complicated processing, depending on the state of the first document. We do not want to duplicate the state in all documents of the second type because lots of them. How to develop MAP function to receive data from the first-type document.

```
{ "_id":"123",
   "public":true 
}
{
"_id":"321",
"owner_id":"123"
"data":"..."
}
function(doc) {
   if (doc._id=="321"){
        // How do get another document like in python, for example
        var doc2 = db[doc.owner_id];
        if (doc2.public) {
           emit(doc._id, null);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this;

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc._id, {"_id":doc.owner_id});
}
```

Then when you do ?key=321&include_docs=true the included doc will be the one with id of doc.owner_id not 321.

More here:
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Linked_documents

Comment: How it can help with map function that depends on data in linked document, not its id?

Comment: That can't be done in CouchDB. A map function only has access to one document at a time.

Comment: Index consistency would be very difficult if every index record needed to know every other document that the index touched so it could update the index when the related document changed.  While desirable, it would be prohibitively expensive.